# Why are my <a> elements not displaying?

Tags: html, css

I am building a navbar and I had everything working yesterday.  My computer lost power last night and I don't have the code from yesterday anymore apparently.  Anyways, my css is:

```
ul {
  float: right;
  background-color: black;
  width: 600px;
}

a {

  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;

}

a:link {
  text-decoration-color: none;
}

a:hover {
background-color: blue;
}

li {
  float: left;
  color: white;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
  padding: 20px 40px 20px 40px; 
}

body {
  background-color: #f0f0f5;
}
```

And the html is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Practice Site</title>
    <link href=main.css rel=text/css type=stylesheet/>
</head>

<body>
    <ul>
        <li><a href=#></a>Home</li>
        <li><a href=#></a>Home</li>
        <li><a href=#></a>Home</li>
        <li><a href=#></a>Home</li>
    </ul>
    <!--Sign up form-->
    <form>
        <p>First Name</p>
        <input type="text" name="First Name" size="20" maxlength="30" />
    </form>
</body>
```

Also, I don't quite understand how I can indent all of the code that I have to display in my questions without using control+v to copy the required indent.  I already read the advanced help and did not see how to do this there.

Comment: "how I can indent all of the code that I have to display in my questions  " — http://i.imgur.com/rLwdiHZ.png

Answer (score 3):

Your `<a>` elements have no content in them. Move the text inside the `<a>` element and you'll see the links.

Change

```
<li><a href=#></a>Home</li>
```

to

```
<li><a href=#>Home</a></li>
```

Comment: Thank you!  That was one of the changes that I made yesterday that I didn't pick up on this afternoon.

Comment: Much appreciated.

Comment: You're welcome. If this answer solved your issue, please mark it correct by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Because they have:

- No content that would give them a height/width
- No CSS that would given them a height/width despite having no content

Put the text **inside** the link instead of after it.

Answer (score 0):

See this code:

```css
ul {
  float: right;
  background-color: black;
  width: 600px;
}

a {

  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
padding: 20px 40px 20px 40px; 
}

a:link {
  text-decoration-color: none;
}

a:hover {
background-color: blue;
}

li {
  float: left;
  color: white;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
}

body {
  background-color: #f0f0f5;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href=#>Home</a></li>
  <li><a href=#>Home</a></li>
  <li><a href=#>Home</a></li>
  <li><a href=#>Home</a></li>
</ul>
<!--Sign up form-->
<form>
<p>First Name</p>
<input type="text" name="First Name" size="20" maxlength="30" />
</form>
```

Comment: this answer would be more useful if you explained how you solved it

Comment: just apply padding to "a" not for "li"